# Application of Permutation Tests

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, simulation, permutation-test, resampling

I don't know how to post the question more formally. Therefore, let me introduce an example.

Suppose you want to estimate the following regression:

$n_i = f(x_i)+\beta \cdot 1[x_i = j]$,

$n_i$ is the number of observations in bin $i$ for variable $x_i$, $f(\cdot)$ is a polynomial of the same variable, and $1[x_i = j]$ an indicator variable for bin $j$. Therefore, this regression approximates the distribution of $x_i$, allowing for a jump in the distribution at bin $j$.

Suppose that $x_i$ consists of two components $x_i=a_i+b_i$ both components follow some distribution. Also assume that the estimate of $\beta$ is $\hat{\beta}>0$.

Question: Suppose that we want to know, whether the distribution of $b_i$ is the cause for the spike in the density ($\beta>0$). The idea is to test this using the following permutation procedure:

1) calculate $\tilde{x_i}=x_i - b_i$

2) Draw a new $b$ for bin $i$ from the distribution of the $b$'s

3) Re-estimate the equation above

4) Repeat 2) and 3) a lot of times to generate a re-sample distribution

5) Check whether the empirical value of $\beta$ is located in the tails of the resample distribution or not

Is this an appropriate approach? What is the assumption that needs to be satisfied. How do I have to interpret the exchangeability condition is this framework?